# How to access repository combobox value in XtraGrid column

Tags: c#, combobox, devexpress, xtragrid

I have a XtraGrid GridControl defined with 3 columns, 2 databound and one I have set to a `RepositoryItemComboBox`. The column is setup like:

```
this.gridColumn3.Caption = "Test";
this.gridColumn3.FieldName = "test";
this.gridColumn3.Name = "gridColumn3";
this.gridColumn3.UnboundType = DevExpress.Data.UnboundColumnType.String;
this.gridColumn3.Visible = true;
this.gridColumn3.VisibleIndex = 2;
```

The `RepositoryItemComboBox` is created like:

```
RepositoryItemComboBox cbo = new RepositoryItemComboBox();

cbo.Items.Add("1");
cbo.Items.Add("2");
cbo.Items.Add("3");
cbo.Items.Add("4");
cbo.Items.Add("5");
cbo.Items.Add("6");
cbo.Items.Add("7");

gridView1.Columns[3].ColumnEdit = cbo;
```

When viewing the grid, the `combobox` displays exactly as I want it. This issue is when trying to retrieve the value selected in the `combobox`. When a `button`, outside of the grid, is pressed the `combobox` value should be processed. I use the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < gridView1.DataRowCount; i++)
{
    int ID = (int)gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "id");
    string Test = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "test").ToString();

    ProcessCombo(ID, Test);
}
```

In the above code `ID` is retrieved as expected, but `gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "test")` returns `null`. What could I have missed out? Is this even the right way to approach this?

Comment: If appears you set the column up as an unbound column, in which case the GridView's CustomUnboundColumnData event needs to be handled in order to provide a value to the cell.

Comment: I have looked at this, but how do you access the value of the combobox in the CustomUnboundColumnData event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ComboBox` editor is only exists when the focused cell is in editing state. So, `ComboBox` is created when you activate it and is destroyed when you go away. So, when your `Button` is pressed there are no `ComboBox` in your `GridView`.

If you want to get the `ComboBox` value then you need to use events of your `RepositoryItemComboBox` or editing events of your `GridView`. The link to the editor is stored in `sender` parameter of `RepositoryItemComboBox` events and in [`GridView.ActiveEditor`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_ActiveEditortopic) property. The value of the `ComboBox` you can get by using [`ComboBox.EditValue`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsBaseEdit_EditValuetopic) property or by using [`GridView.EditingValue`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_EditingValuetopic) property. Also you can get the value by using `EventArgs` parameter of `GridView` editing events like `ValidatedEditor`, `CellValueChanging`, `CellValueChanged`.

For example:

```
private void RepositoryItemComboBox1_Closed(object sender, ClosedEventArgs e)
{
    //Get the value from sender:
    var comboBox = (ComboBoxEdit)sender;
    object value = comboBox.EditValue;

    //Get the value from active editor:
    object activeEditorValue = gridView1.ActiveEditor.EditValue;

    //Get the value from editing value:
    object editingValue = gridView1.EditingValue;
}
```

Also, if you want to store your value and use it later then you can use [`ColumnView.CustomUnboundColumnData`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_CustomUnboundColumnDatatopic) event.

Here is example:

```
private Dictionary<int, string> _comboBoxValues = new Dictionary<int, string>();

private void gridView1_CustomUnboundColumnData(object sender, CustomColumnDataEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column.FieldName != "test")
        return;

    int id = (int)gridView1.GetListSourceRowCellValue(e.ListSourceRowIndex, "id");

    if (e.IsSetData)
        _comboBoxValues[id] = (string)e.Value;
    else if (e.IsGetData && _comboBoxValues.ContainsKey(id))
        e.Value = _comboBoxValues[id];
}
```

Comment: So how do I apply this value to the cell and retrieve it on the button press?

Comment: @anothershrubery You cannot apply this value directly to the cell. There are no storage for cell values inside of `GridView`. For bound columns the values for cell are retrieved from data source that you assign to `GridControl`. For unbound columns the values are calculated by `GridColumn.UnboundExpression` property or defined in [`GridView.CustomUnboundColumnData`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_CustomUnboundColumnDatatopic) event.

Comment: Yeah, so it doesn't answer the question then? I know how to get the values like above, but need to access them via a button press outside of the grid.

Comment: @anothershrubery So, it's unclear what you asking. Your question is about «How to get value from ComboBox?» or «How to store value from ComboBox (or some another editor) in unbound column?»?

Comment: @anothershrubery I have added example for storing and retrieving values by using `ColumnView.CustomUnboundColumnData` event.

Comment: Well if you read the content of the question, rather than the title, you would see what was required. When setting the question, I didn't know there was a way to work with `CustomUnboundColumnData`. But thank you for the answer, I have marked it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to change the column to a bound field, passed in an empty string when populating the grid, and now I can access the data via:

```
string Test = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "test").ToString();
```

Didn't want to do this, but it works so...